# Bind the table body with n number of columns in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am getting data from API with unknown columns name. I am able to bind table headers but unable to bind tbody row's column..
Data will be like this for ex.

```
  [{name: "jean", surname: "kruger"}, {name: "bobby", surname: "marais"}];
OR
  [{name: "jean", email: "a@a.com"}, {name: "bobby", email: "b@b.com"}]; // anything

<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th *ngFor="let col of headers">{{col}}></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let obj of data">
         <td *ngFor="let col of headers"> {{obj[col]}} </td> // Its not working
                               OR
          <td *ngFor="let col of headers"> {{obj.col}} </td> // Its not working, will be column sequence mapping issue
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**How to over come this problem ?
Thanks.. **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code sample, I created. I think, I fixed your issue there.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbx49v